# WGET Download specific folders under an apache directory

Tags: wget

I want to download some folders under the same directories by using `wget`, here is the structure of the `apache` directory.

```
example.com/main/eschool/PhotoAlbum/Album/2008-10-13-citieneducationcenter/

example.com/main/eschool/PhotoAlbum/Album/2009-11-12-snfkdgjndfk/

example.com/main/eschool/PhotoAlbum/Album/2012-10-9-dsngosdgndfk/
```

...

It is found that there is a pattern:

`example.com/main/eschool/PhotoAlbum/Album/20*`, is it possible to download all those folders?

Comment: There's always bruteforce :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to download everything under `example.com/main/eschool/PhotoAlbum/Album/`, but not above it, you can use the `--recursive` and `--no-parent` options:

```
wget --no-parent --recursive http://example.com/main/eschool/PhotoAlbum/Album/
```

That will download everything below `Album` directory. If you want to limit how deep `wget` dives into the subdirectories, you can specify the `--level` option:

```
wget --no-parent --recursive --level=3 http://example.com/main/eschool/PhotoAlbum/Album/
```

That will drill down up to 3 subdirectories below `Album`.

However, neither of these methods filter by name – they will blindly download *everything* in a directory, and its subdirectories. If you want more control (e.g. to only download albums beginning with `20*`), you'll have to use a shell script, or a scripting language.